# Switching universities/research groups after PhD

Tags: postdocs, job-search

I am finishing up my PhD thesis at a top university. I have been given the advice that, for an academic career, moving universities for your postdoc is generally a good idea as you are exposed to new faculty/ideas.

I have however found a postdoc opportunity at my current university, but within a different department (mathematics as opposed to engineering) which I am interested in. Is this just as good for my career as moving to a new university? Or are academic committees focused on a big change in environment for networking purposes?

Many thanks!

Comment: As long as you write papers without your PhD supervisor in order to demonstrate your independence, staying at the same university should not be held against you. But, better to decide when you have offers in hand, so apply and see what happens.